# Loop thru form to fill json object for post

Tags: javascript, json, post

I have a shopping cart and want to post it to my login window so I can proceed to checkout after authentication. But before this can be achieved, I am using a webservice call on shoppingcart window load, so I can get a hash of my cart items and secure the communication between us. How can I serialize all my cart items in the data object so I can send it to my webserver?

This is what I am trying so far, but it isn't working...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  getCartHashCode();
});

function getCartHashCode() {
  var url = 'home/GetHashRequest';
  var data = new Array();

  //put all items from the cart on the data object
  for (i = 1; i <= $('.product-name').length; i++) {
    //setting up json parameter names
    var CART_NAME = 'CART_'+i+'_NAME';
    var CART_PRICE = 'CART_'+i+'_PRICE';

    var obj = { CART_NAME: $('input[name=Cart['+i+'].Name').val(),
                CART_PRICE: $('input[name=Cart['+i+'].Price').val() }

    data.push(obj);
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function (hash) {
      alert("It worked! Hash = " + hash.toString());
    }
  });
```

***EDIT***

Follow up after ferrants' comment: I took it off, and really did go to the server! Thanks

The problem is how do I get the items I posted on the server side?

I have a `item` domain class defined as this:

```
public class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller action is this:

```
public string GetHashRequest(List<Item> cart)
{
  GetSecureHashPOCORequest hashRequest = new GetSecureHashPOCORequest();
}
```

Comment: You should be able to pass it without the data.serialize().

Comment: Have you tried using `serializeArray()` instead of loop-building your form stuff?  http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: @AJ, yes I did... didn't work